# can't set Struts2 result type to json

Tags: json, struts2

I want to use json with Struts2. However, when I set the action return type to "json", I got "there is no result type defined for type 'json' mapped with name 'success'." Bellow is struts.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="resource"/>

    <package extends="struts-default" name="test">
        <action name="inputHandler" class="inputHandlerAction">
            <result name="input">/index.jsp</result>
            <result>/result.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="setLangHandler" class="com.sesoft.test.setLanguageHandler">
            <result>/index.jsp</result>
        </action>

        <action name="Handler" class="com.sesoft.test.Handler">
            <result>/test2.jsp</result>
        </action>   
    </package>

    <package name="example" extends="json-default">

        <action name="ajaxHandler" class="com.sesoft.test.AjaxHandler">
            <result name="success" type="json" />
        </action>

    </package>
</struts>
```

Before I added the json Action, all other action performs fine. But after I added the json Action, the server failed to action with error code 503.

libs I've added "jsonplugin-0.33.jar" to the lib directory.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You don't have the JSON result defined in your struts.xml package. If you only need default things then you can just extend json-default instead of struts-default. If you need to customise the package then include the following and that should do the trick:

```
    <result-types>
        <result-type name="json" class="com.googlecode.jsonplugin.JSONResult"/>
    </result-types>
```

Comment: Seems Google Plugin for json has been replaced with Struts2 Json Plugin: https://cwiki.apache.org/S2PLUGINS/json-plugin.html `The JSON plugin is bundled with Struts since 2.1.7+. The plugin at Google Code has been deprecated.`

Comment: @I.G.Pascual Your link is broken. Please update.

Comment: @RahatZaman there is not way to edit a comment. But I'll share the updated url here (it's been 9 years now!) https://struts.apache.org/plugins/json/

Answer (score 12):

you package should extends  json-default

```
<package name="json-default" extends="struts-default">
    <result-types>
        <result-type name="json" class="org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult"/>
    </result-types>
    <interceptors>
        <interceptor name="json" class="org.apache.struts2.json.JSONInterceptor"/>
    </interceptors>
</package>
```

Comment: I actually love you. You have just saved me after hours and hours of pain and suffering. Thank you for writing this 6 years ago so that in 2017 my life would be a little less awful.

Answer (score 0):

If using Maven you may need to add the dependency e.g.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-json-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my configuration in `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-json-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

In the action result you only need to specify `type="json"` :

```
<result type="json"/>
```

Remember the variable getter and setter in `type="json"` response give getters in the action.

Answer (score 0):

Include `json-default` in the `extends` parameter:

```
<package name="default" extends="struts-default,json-default">
   <action> 
       ...
       ...
  </action>
</package>
```