# How to create struts action with result type as "json"

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, json, struts2

I created the following action

```
@Action(value = "searchPersonByName", results = {@Result(type = "json",
    params = {"status", "204" }) })
public List<Person> searchPerson() {
    return new ArrayList<Person>();
}
```

Deploying struts application with this action throws the following error

> Caused by: The Result type [json] which is defined in the Result annotation on the class [class com.mk.gk.actions.PersonAction] or determined by the file extension or is the default result type for the PackageConfig of the action, could not be found as a result-type defined for the Struts/XWork package [com.mk.gk.actions#/#/] - [unknown location]

I want to call this action in jquery.ajax with dataType as "json". How to achieve this? How to get this action type as **json**.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/916285/cant-set-struts2-result-type-to-json

Comment: I am new to sruts. Can you point me how to add class information in action results annotation as per the above stackoverflow link

Comment: You should provide it if needed to the parent package, at the moment Struts2 doesn't have annotation based configuration equivalent.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Ajax - issue returning JSON value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17093862/jquery-ajax-issue-returning-json-value)

Answer (score 2):

Struts2 [now supports](https://struts.apache.org/docs/convention-plugin.html#ConventionPlugin-ParentPackageannotation) specifying the parent package through annotations. Consequently, this error can also be resolved by adding the annotation `@ParentPackage("json-default")` to your class, assuming you are using the [Convention Plugin](https://struts.apache.org/docs/convention-plugin.html), which is now common practice.

Answer (score 0):

1. Include **[Struts2-Convention-Plugin](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/convention-plugin.html)**
2. Include **[Struts2-JSON-Plugin](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/json-plugin.html)**
3. In you `struts.xml`, make your Package extending `json-default`.

Check out the **[Struts2-jQuery-Plugin](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/)** too, to perform jQuery stuff easily.